# Como remover um item selecionado numa treeview c#

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

estou desenvolvendo uma nova aplicaçao mas estou com um problema final por resolver e ja tentei googlear e nada nao consigo encontrar nenhum exemplo.

de facto eu quero apagar o item na treeview que foi selesionado

eu tentei assim mas da me um erro

> Error 1   'System.Windows.Forms.TreeView' does not contain a definition for 'Items' and no extension method 'Items' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.TreeView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

eu tentei assim :

```
listMessages.Items.Remove(listMessages.SelectedItem);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não existem as propriedades `Items` e `SelectedItem` em uma *tree view* do Windows Forms.

Você precisa usar [`Nodes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.nodes(v=vs.110).aspx) no lugar de `Items` e [`SelectedNode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.selectednode(v=vs.110).aspx) no lugar de `SelectedItem`.

[Veja a documentação oficial do controle.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.treeview(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
listMessages.Nodes.Remove(listMessages.SelectedNode);
```

Comment: Por que é preciso usar `Nodes` ao invés de `Items`?

Comment: Porque `Items` não existe, @Francisco